# Unable to style data in react to view as mono space

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I am displaying some data on UI using react but i'm unable to format it.

The data i'm trying to display:

```
["----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n",
 "DEPT >= 0;                                                  ¦ Y N N N N N N\n",
 "NEW;                                                        ¦   Y N N N N N\n",
 "¬OLD;                                                       ¦     Y N N N N\n"]
```

How it is getting displayed:

[image]

How i want it to get displayed:

[image]

Currently i'm using `Courier New` as font-family under the impression of it being a homogeneous font but somehow i'm getting the expected result.

I have also tried with `monospace` font family.

```
<div style={{fontSize:"11px", fontFamily:"Courier New"}}>
{this.state.codeData.map(item=>
    <p key={Math.random()}>
        {item}
    </p>)}
</div>
```

Please help or suggest some appropriate link which may help me to get the job done.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your data in a `<pre> {item} </pre>` tag

Answer (score 0):

By default the browser will collapse multiple white space characters (as spaces and tabs etc) into a single one. This gives you some degrees of freedom to format the source code.

You can use the `pre` element to keep those spaces as you put them into the source or use the [white-space css property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to control that behaviour.